Ability of Peano axiom with integer set?
Axioms:

Peano Axioms (defines natural number, introducing 0 and ')
For each predicate φ, there exist exactly one set X, s.t. forall x, φ(x) <=> x∈X.

So, it's possible to define less-than in First-order logic as:
$$ x < y : (x \neq y) ∧ [\forall X, (x\in X)∧(∀t∈X, t'∈X)\rightarrow y∈X]$$
Questions:

Can this model define addition? (Note that sets of sets are not supported)
Can this model define multiplication?
Can this model construct uncomputable questions?


The Peano axioms define addition and multiplication.  Once you have addition you can define less than as $x \lt y \iff \exists b (x+b=y)$

@RossMillikan That part isn't introduced into this model

According to Wikipedia what I was thinking of as Peano axioms are correctly called Peano arithmetic.  Sorry for the confusion

In more standard terminology, you're asking about the monadic second-order theory of the natural numbers with sucessor ("monadic second-order" means that you can quantify over sets, but not relations of arity $>1$). This -  and indeed much more - is decidable, so the answer to all three of your questions is negative. See wiki, or Rabin's famous paper on the monadic second-order theory of the binary tree.
(And if you want a glimpse at how messy things can get with more complicated orderings, look at Shelah's The monadic theory of order.)
